# How to sort records of child table? Parse API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parse-platform

I have used Parse as a back-end(Parse API: https://parse.com). I am searching for the way to sort the records of child table.

Table structures,

**User**

objectId, FirstName, LastName, Age

**Friend**

objectId, myId, FriendId

`FriendId` is a pointer to User table.

Now I want to retrieve all records of Friend table where `myId=X` and record should be shorted based on FirstName.

Any help would be appreciated

***Edit:***
Sorting records at iPhone side will not work because **parse providing only 1000 records at a time** but my table has more than 3000 records.
I have only one way and that is fetch all the records recursively and sort them. But I am looking for way to sort records at server side instead of at client side.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to do this using Parse's built-in query API. You'll have to sort the records after pulling them. Here's an example:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friend"];
[query includeKey:@"friendId"];

NSArray * friends = [query findObjects];
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"friendId.FirstName" 
                                                            ascending:Yes];

NSArray * sortedFriends = [friends sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
// now sorted by the first name of User
```

This assumes that you have the pointer to the User class set up properly

Comment: I knew this approach see my edits but sorry for that I missed to clarify in question like I am looking for a way to sort record at server side. +1 for your effort

Comment: Oh I see, yeah unfortunately they don't support that at the moment. I ran into the same issue. Why exactly do you need to sort server side?

Comment: I want to keep the paging in my application and one of reason is too keep the low memory footprint

Comment: Looked at your edit, sort of understand. So you want the first 1000 sorted elements? And on iOS, unless you're downloading large images or anything like that the memory footprint is very low. The data does not take up much space. Sorting the elements may or may not take up significant time, though.

Comment: Also, you can always write a javascript cloud function to return 1000 of the sorted elements, but that gets complicated.